# How to remove the space between each td inside a table with css?

Tags: html, css

I've created a table but on mobile and tablet there are white lines that separate each td. Any solution to remove these without refactoring the whole table?

I've tried alot of other solutions that's close to my issue. For example, border="0" or "1", border-collpase (already have it applied) etc.
The thicker white line is fine it's just the small ones in each td
[image: Example Picture of white lines]

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-width: 30px 10px 10px 0px;
  /* padding: 15px 15px 15px 5px; */
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.spacer{
  display:  none;
}


 table .tr-border td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0456A1;
  }
  table .tr-border-top{
    border-top: 1px solid #0456A1;
  }
  
  table .tr-border .line-break{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  }

.line-break-2{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0456A1;
}

.table-head-text {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 3%;
  color: #0d56a4;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "UniversLTStd-BoldCn";
}

td {
  border: none;
  color: #5b5a5a;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 15px;
  font-family: "UniversLTStd-LightCn";
}

/*.left-td{
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 25px;
}*/

.bk {
  background: #d0d2d3;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.bottom-table-text{
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}

.table-year-1 {
  background: #0d56a4;
  color: #d0d2d3;
  padding-right: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 1%;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: "UniversLTStd-Cn";
}

span.loss-span {
  display: block;
}

.table-year-2 {
  background: #5b5a5a;
  color: #d0d2d3;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 1%;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 8px;
  font-family: "UniversLTStd-Cn";
}

.bottom-number{
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.bottom-number-2{
  padding-top:25px;
}

.bottom-number-3{
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-family: "UniversLTStd-Cn";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.left-td-3{
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.top-year-text{
  padding-top:15px;
}

.block-text{
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.bold{
  font-family: "UniversLTStd-Cn";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.border {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0456A1;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-head-text top-table-text left-td-2">Assets</td>
      <td class="table-year-1 bold top-year-text">2018</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2 bold top-year-text">2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-td left-td-2">Cash &amp; Due From Banks</td>
      <td class="table-year-1">$149,753</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2">$77,515</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-td left-td-2">Investment Securities</td>
      <td class="table-year-1">$929,432</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2">$830,878</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-td left-td-2">Loans <span class="soc-head-text-1">(net of valuation reserve)</span> <span class="soc-head-text-2">($28,582 in 2018 &amp; <span class="soc-head-text-1">$27,063 in 2017)</span></span>
      </td>
      <td class="table-year-1 bottom-number">$1,902,960</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2 bottom-number">$1,813,062</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-td left-td-2">Federal Funds Sold</td>
      <td class="table-year-1">$0</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2">$0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-td left-td-2">Premises &amp; Equipment</td>
      <td class="table-year-1">$49,956</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2">$46,666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-td left-td-2">Accured Income</td>
      <td class="table-year-1">$12,652</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2">$12,589</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-td left-td-2">Other Assets</td>
      <td class="table-year-1">$111,287</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2">$102,413</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
      <td class="table-head-text left-td-2">Total Assets</td>
      <td class="table-year-1 bold line-break">$3,156,040</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2 bold line-break">$2,883,123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-head-text top-table-text left-td-3">Liabilities &amp; <span class="soc-head-text-1">Capital Funds</span></td>
      <td class="table-year-1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-td left-td-2">Non-Interest Bearing <span class="soc-head-text-1">Deposits</span></td>
      <td class="table-year-1">$952,623</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2">$894,075</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-td left-td-2">Non-Interest Bearing <span class="soc-head-text-1">Public Deposits</span></td>
      <td class="table-year-1 bottom-number-2">$190,104</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2 bottom-number-2">$179,582</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-td left-td-2">Interest Bearing Deposits</td>
      <td class="table-year-1">$1,344,490</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2">$1,194,226</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-td left-td-2">Interest Bearing <span class="soc-head-text-1">Public Deposits</span></td>
      <td class="table-year-1 bottom-number-2">$370,094</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2 bottom-number-2">$274,994</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
      <td class="table-head-text left-td-2">Total Deposits</td>
      <td class="table-year-1 bold line-break">$2,857,311</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2 bold line-break">$2,542,877</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="block-text left-td left-td-2">Other Liabilities</td>
      <td class="table-year-1 block-text">$22,497</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2 block-text">$22,954</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-td left-td-2">Fed Funds Purchase &amp; <span class="soc-head-text-1">Other Borrowed Money</span></td>
      <td class="table-year-1 bottom-number-2">$0</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2 bottom-number-2">$63,394</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
      <td class="table-head-text left-td left-td-2">Total Liabilities</td>
      <td class="table-year-1 bold line-break">$2,879,808</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2 bold line-break">$2,629,225</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-head-text top-table-text left-td-3">Capital Accounts</td>
      <td class="table-year-1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-td left-td-2">Capital Stock</td>
      <td class="table-year-1">$2,500</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2">$2,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-td left-td-2">Surplus</td>
      <td class="table-year-1">$100,943</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2">$79,188</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-td left-td-2">Undivided Proﬁts</td>
      <td class="table-year-1">$188,173</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2">$177,768</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-td left-td-2">Unrealized Gain <span class="loss-span"><span class="soc-head-text-1">(Loss) Securities</span></span>
      </td>
      <td class="table-year-1 bottom-number-2">($15,384)</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2 bottom-number-2">($5,558)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
      <td class="table-head-text left-td-2 left-td-4">Total Capital Accounts</td>
      <td class="table-year-1 line-break bottom-number-3">$276,232</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2 line-break bottom-number-3">$253,898</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-head-text bk"><span class="bottom-table-text">Total Liabilities &amp; <span class="soc-head-text-1">Capital Accounts</span></span>
      </td>
      <td class="table-year-1 line-break-2 bottom-number-3">$3,156,040</td>
      <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-year-2 line-break-2 bottom-number-3">$2,883,123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border-top">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please include your CSS

Comment: Your question title is _"How to remove table data **cells** inside a table in html?"_ but reading your question, you don't want to remove the **cells** -- you want to remove the space _between_ cells. Please re-title your question. Also, as jo_va requests, your question is completely _**unanswerable**_ without your CSS.

Comment: Added css. Sorry, question is re titled

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `outline` and `border` property to `none` for `td`.

```
outline: none;
border: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try using

> border-collapse: separate;

in .table?

Comment: yea and it separates them more instead of removing the space